# OAuth access_token request -> forbidden

Tags: api, token, instagram

Yesterday I wanted to get an access_token from my account, tried several websites, every time I tried it I got a white page with "Forbidden".

Does Instagram lock the API Access from User?

- Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution

1. login to your instagram account from pc browser
2. go to Edit Profile
3. change some of your profile info. example: add or delete some text to Bio
4. Click submit. a new screen will apear which show you a security picture type the text from picture.
   after that you will be able to get access token.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have any problem, using oauth.io with a simple Instagram connect:

```
OAuth.popup("instagram", function(e,r) {
    if (e) {
        $('#results').html('error: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
        return
    }

    $('#results').html('result from instragram: ' + JSON.stringify(r));
});
```

You can try directly on http://jsfiddle.net/bumpmann/4Ef8p/ and it should reply something like:
`{"access_token":"...","user":  {"username":"...","bio":"...","website":"...","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/...","full_name":"...","id":"123456789"}}`

If you don't get that, you have most likely a problem with your Instagram account (or your environment if it works on another device)

Comment: I have the same problem and I know why.. I have a foreign mobile number from germany and the text message with the auth code can't be delivered for whatever reason..

Answer (score 2):

You got "forbidden" because of new instagram "captcha" feature. I cannot still find any official information about it, but if user passes captcha on his mobile, authorization will work again.

Answer (score 0):

For the people those don't understand.

Just go to instagram and reset your password than you will see the captcha.

After filling this in you can retreve the acces token with your application